# Why should zipcode values not be placed in Boyce Codd Normal Form?

Tags: database, database-design, normalization, database-normalization, denormalization

Can someone explain to me why it is that zipcodes should not be placed in Boyce Codd Normal Form? Is there really any more to it other than that zipcodes are unlikely to change in any foreseeable point in time?

Comment: Could you provide an example of what are you actually trying to ask?

Comment: Sorry for being a little unclear. I was trying to understand the reasoning, but also find another good example besides zipcodes. Something that doesn't change often enough that you would, for time and effort, really worry about splitting such a value into BCNF for a data table structure.

Comment: Sorry I still do not get it -- for example table `ZipCode{Zip} KEY {ZIP}` is in 6NF (hence also in 5, 4, BCNF, 3, 2, 1). What exactly are you trying to split?

Answer (score 3):

You should only place zip codes in 3NF or BCNF if your intention is to lookup other information based on them (such as locale).  In that context, a zip code becomes a "natural key."

Absent that context, there doesn't seem to be much point.  In most applications, a zip code is merely treated as a bit of text, and doesn't have any contextual meaning otherwise.

Comment: I see. Is there any situation besides zipcodes that you would choose to not ideally place a database table into BCNF?

Comment: There are many.  Any time it would be undesirable or unnecessary to perform a lookup.

Comment: Yes, like SSN.  Unless you are the Social Security Administration.

Comment: @Robert, I don't get it. Are you talking about decomposing SSN or Zipcode into a relation of its own? I can't see what that has to do with BCNF. Maybe you could give an actual example to explain what you mean.

Comment: I, too, don't understand what this has to do with BCNF specifically.  It seems to me the question is: "why wouldn't zip codes be stored in a separate table/relation?"  +1 on the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Zipcode is an attribute whereas BCNF is a property satisfied by a *relation* or set of relations. As a general rule, aim to be in at least BCNF unless and until you have a good reason to deviate from that. On that basis I'd suggest that relations with a zipcode attribute ought to be in BCNF. What makes you think otherwise?

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you are talking about 2NF, not the minor difference between 3NF and BCNF, (cause zipcodes don't seem to be relevant to BCNF), then:
Yes, that, and the fact that it is unnecessarily obtuse, saves only one byte of storage, (zipcodes are five chars and can be stored in 5 bytes, an integer Foreign Key is 4 bytes),  and requires an additional join to retrieve the value.

Comment: Normalization has nothing to do with storage size!

Comment: If it involves creating another table, with Foreign keys to get the values from the other table, as it would here, to satisfy 2NF, to create a ZipCode table to avoid duplication of non-dependant data,  it certainly does.

Comment: But nothing about 2NF, BCNF or any other NF requires a zipcode to be replaced by a 4 byte integer and there's no apparent reason why moving a zipcode attribute itself to another table would eliminate any dependency that would otherwise violate any NF (except maybe 6NF). Again, normalization has *nothing* to do with storage size and is entirely orthogonal to the datatype or size of any attribute.